# Sensing the voltage between drain and source in a flyback converter

Tags: flyback

I want to monitor the voltage between drain and source of the main switch in a flyback converter and use it to control the active clamp switch.
Does using resistive voltage divider across the switch make any problem?
If so how else is it possible to sense the voltage?

Comment: Leakage from your voltage divider comes to mind. Alternative solution is via auxiliary winding.

Comment: Most folk would use a zener diode and an RC to act as a diode clamp. Why do you think it's important to monitor the flyback voltage and use some active clamp circuit? It's not as if you are dealing with kilowatts here AND, any active clamping circuit will have a serious propagation delay that might not prevent adequate clamping.